# How to make my jComboBox take data from database in netbeans

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, combobox

I have an application who manage to rent cars, and I want two combo box to take the data that I need from my database, for example :
I want to rent an Audi A4: Combobox1 to select Audi from the database, and combobox2 to show me all the Audi cars (a1,a2,a3,q4, etc) and to choose the one I want. I tried with try{catch but it's not working the way I want it to do.
I would remain grateful to you guys if you can help me with that. Thank you!

That's the code I tried with

```
try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Inchirieri-Auto", "TUDOR", "tudor");
            String s="select MODEL from AUTOTURISME where MARCA='"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase()+"'";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(s);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                jComboBox3.addItem(rs.getString(1));
            }



        }catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
```

where AUTOTURISME = cars, MODEL=A1, A2, and MARCA = the brand of the car (Audi, BMW)

For now, it is not taking any data from the database

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on "its not working the way i want it to do".  What is happening?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: try to print `jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase()` and see what does it have in it , also that is not correct way to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: It's not working the way i want it to do because when i open the combobox, it empty. no info regarding the data that i wanted to be showed there.

Comment: does `jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase()`  have anything in it ?